# DB connection Error In PHP Slim framework in mac Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out

Tags: php, database, slim

I have installed Xampp VM in mac for PHP slim framework(V3).
get an error when try to connect remote db over the internet using vpn.
error is **Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out**
but xampp local db connect without any error.
I used this code for connecting.

```
class db
{
    public $dbhost = '192.168.1.78';
    public $dbuser = 'root';
    public $dbpass = 'Raven898';
    public $dbname = 'xyz';
    public $dbport = '3306';

    // Connect
    public function connect()
    {
        $connection = 'mysql:host='.$this->dbhost.';dbname='.$this->dbname;
        try {
            $dbh = new PDO($connection, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Connection failed: '.$e->getMessage();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You're probably not allowed to connect to the database remotely.

Comment: that way to set the db connection is from slim 2, are you sure about the version?

Comment: @miken32 my workbanch connected successfully using same vpn only slim not connected i dont know why

Comment: Yes @DaFois i double check after your comment its v3.0